# Angular File Upload Change event not passing correct index of ngFor

Tags: angular

```
<div formArrayName="employee" *ngFor="let document of employeeForm.get('ems').controls; let i = index">
            
<input id="file_up" type="file" (change)="upload($event,i,document.get('name').value)"/>                                           
        
                    
</div>
```

When Any file is selected and its change event is called it is passing the initial value of index I, not the current value? How to get the current value of I in change event is called?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div formArrayName="employee" *ngFor="let document of employeeForm.get('ems').controls; let i = index">
            
<input #file_up type="file" (change)="upload($event,i,document.get('name').value)"/>                                           
        
<button id="btn" (click)="file_up.click()"></button>
                    
</div>
```

Comment: I want to pass selected  value of index i when any file is selected and change event is called without using button ?

Comment: Could you add some information about how this helps OP?

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of dynamic loops, always try to give a `trackBy` function to `*ngFor`

```
<div formArrayName="employee" *ngFor="let document of employeeForm.get('ems').controls; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFun">
            
<input id="file_up" type="file" (change)="upload($event,i,document.get('name').value)"/>                                           
        
                    
</div>
```

In .ts

```
trackByFun(index, object){
    return index;
}
```